# print iPad screen code

Tags: xcode, ipad, printing, airprint

do you think is it possible add a code in  an application (xcode) that allows print the screen of ipad, or send it to the mac

Answer (score 1):

```
#import "AirPrintingViewController.h"

@implementation AirPrintingViewController

-(void)printItem {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo" ofType:@"png"];
    NSData *dataFromPath = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

    UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

    if(printController && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:dataFromPath]) {

        printController.delegate = self;

        UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
        printInfo.jobName = [path lastPathComponent];
        printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
        printController.printInfo = printInfo;
        printController.showsPageRange = YES;
        printController.printingItem = dataFromPath;

        void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
            if (!completed && error) {
                NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u", error.domain, error.code);
            }
        };

        [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(printItem) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [btn setTitle:@"PRINT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 50);
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}

@end
```

,

with this code I can print a file in the path, how can I print my screen instead the file already in the path?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but *only* from your *own* apps. You cannot send screenshots of other apps.

Comment: To print, look into AirPrint. To send it to the Mac, ask yourself how you want to transfer it - Webbrowser, Email, a native client. For grabbing a screenshot, you need to search here. Please post another (specific) question for concrete problems.

Comment: thank you for your help. I am making an app with several questions on iPad. when I finish to answer all the questions I want to print this file and save as pdf as well. I cannot do the press home button and click sleep button to capture the screen because the file I am using is 1900 instead 1024 so it will take only the ipad resolution leaving out the rest. I hope I have been clear.

Comment: hey @Marco I need to do exactly this.you got any solution?